# Flutter Navigator - Swap Pages From The Page Stack

Tags: flutter

My situation is a bit tedious. I am pushing 2 pages to navigator

A - B

B is pushed latest.

For some reasons. I dont want to pop B to navigate from B to A. I want to replace / swap them. The reasons are due to states. I want to keep the states of both A and B pages as there are some widgets which are extremely costly to build (Unity view widget). From B how can I use Navigator so that without destroying my pages I can swap B with A?

Here is the flow:

- A opens as the default page.
- B is pushed with

  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed();

  Page Stack is A - B
- From B I want to navigate to A while still keeping the B page alive.
- -After some magical operations I am missing -
- Page Stack is B - A. The user sees the page A. None of the pages were destroyed. They were swapped.

Is there a way to do this in Flutter?

Comment: use `Navigator` 2.0? (i mean `MaterialApp.router`)

Comment: It seems too complicated and my app is already setup with lots of routes in it. This would be a option for last resort. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: afaik you can mix them too, see https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q0jx0l4-xymph9O6zLaOY4d_f7YFpNWX_eGbzYxr9wY/edit#heading=h.ririyyxrggqr and ^F `Pageless Routes`

Comment: i honestly dont think its even possible with Navigator 2.0, am i missing something?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? @csguy

Answer (score 3):

You can use `PageView` for simple way and set config like this:

```
PageController _pagerController = PageController(keepPage: true);

PageView(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      controller: _pagerController,
      children: [
         Page_A(),
         Page_B(),
      ],
),
```

And for switching between pages:

```
goNextPage() {
  _pagerController.animateToPage(
    currentPage + 1,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    curve: Curves.ease,
  );
}

goPrevPage() {
  _pagerController.animateToPage(
    currentPage - 1,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    curve: Curves.ease,
  );
}
```

I hope it's useful for you.

Comment: this is a smart solution but does PageView ensure the widgets that are not visible are onhold state? By that I mean i think when u push a new page with navigator old page doesnt doesnt eat that much of memory. with this pageview approach wouldnt every single page be still active in memory?

Comment: Yes, two pages are alive. But it depends on the type of data you use, if the data is as simple as a class model, you can store model in static field and when user click to switch 2nd page, use this model to complete Page_B, but if all of Page_B is important, like scrolling, filled textFields & ... , simple way is using `PageView`.

Comment: this lacks custom animations such as fade which are very important for a page change :(

Comment: this is your customize! you can use a lot of transitions for this! like: "https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-pageview-in-flutter-with-custom-transitions-581d9ea6dded" or "https://pub.dev/packages/transformer_page_view" or "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63010195/flutter-fade-animation-between-page-views" :(

Comment: no its not because it doesnt allow for custom animations. I want full control over the anims. Not some predefined animations. I want the same as navigator animations

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [IndexedStack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html) is what you are looking for. It change between widget like TV channel . The widget won't be rebuilt when changing.

As your demand, switch page with animation, `AnimatedSwitcher` seems to be most closely to what your want except **it does rebuild Widget**. So I think `IndexedStack` is a good start for what you want.

You can also refer to [animated_indexed_stack.dart](https://gist.github.com/cirnok/e1b70f5d841e47c9d85ccdf6ae866984) or [AnimatedSwitcher with IndexedStack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59535289/666221) mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48217)

Comment: i want to keep the animations

Comment: I update the answer with some example how others implement animated IndexedStack.

Comment: i cannot afford to rebuild the widget because with each rebuild it takes around 3 secondsfor unity to be active. I create this widget in splash screen and keep it there the whole app

Answer (score -1):

PageView , ListView and GridView builders are designed for high number of objects. And rebuild when scrolling

Column or Row save all  their children builds.

Yo can try :

SingleChildScrollView(NeverScrollable) -> Row -> A(equal screen size) and B(same)

And than animate or jump to :

For  A  offset 0 and for B offset screen width.

I have try, works fine

[image]

```dart
    
///
class AtoBExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AtoBExampleState createState() => _AtoBExampleState();
}

class _AtoBExampleState extends State<AtoBExample> {
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  _toB() {
    // !!! Forward or any operations animations in here
    // e.g animate A's opacity 1 to 0 and wait finish

    scrollController.jumpTo(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);

    // And animate B's opacity 0 to 1
  }

  _toA() {
    // !!! Forward or any operations animations in here
    // e.g animate B's opacity 1 to 0 and wait finish

    scrollController.jumpTo(0);

    // And animate A's opacity 0 to 1
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: scrollController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            // A
            Builder(
              builder: (c) {
                print('GREEN BUILD');
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: (){
                    print('TO B');
                    _toB();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: size.width,
                    height: size.height,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            Builder(
              builder: (c) {
                print('RED BUILD');
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: (){
                    print('TO A');
                    _toA();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: size.width,
                    height: size.height,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: read the comments on the other answers before posting. I already said "this lacks custom animations such as fade which are very important for a page change :( " This applies to your answer as well.

Comment: @csguy Sorry. But I want to add : For fade animation wrap A widget with Transform.opacity() and define opacity with animation value. Forward this animation in (e.g) _toA method.  If you use this , you should use jumpTo. Not animateTo